# Trying to finish an Activity while the device is asleep

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a Service that constantly monitors user speed, and once it goes over a specific value, starts an Activity that the user can't go out off. While this activity is visible, I keep getting user speed in the service. This speed value is constantly sent to the Activity using a LocalBroadcastReceiver so that when it goes down enough this Activity can call finish on itself.

While this activity is visible, and I press the power button to lock the device the service keeps running and I keep getting the speed values. But I am not able to send these values to the Activity, so that while the device is asleep (Activity being visible) and user speed goes down below a particular value, the activity does not get finished. I tried WakeLocks. It didn't work.

Thanks